# Difference between LinearRegression() and Ridge(alpha=0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

The Tikhonov (ridge) cost becomes equivalent to the least squares cost when the alpha parameter approaches zero. Everything on the [scikit-learn docs about the subject](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) indicates the same. Therefore I expected

```
sklearn.linear_model.Ridge(alpha=1e-100).fit(data, target)
```

to be equivalent to

```
sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(data, target)
```

But that's not the case. Why?

**Updated with code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

dataset = pd.read_csv('house_price_data.csv')

X = dataset['sqft_living'].reshape(-1, 1)
Y = dataset['price'].reshape(-1, 1)

polyX = PolynomialFeatures(degree=15).fit_transform(X)

model1 = LinearRegression().fit(polyX, Y)
model2 = Ridge(alpha=1e-100).fit(polyX, Y)

plt.plot(X, Y,'.',
         X, model1.predict(polyX),'g-',
         X, model2.predict(polyX),'r-')
```

*Note:* the plot looks the same for `alpha=1e-8` or `alpha=1e-100`

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge), `alpha` must be a positive float.  Your example has `alpha=0` as an integer.  Using a small positive `alpha`, the results of `Ridge` and `LinearRegression` appear to converge.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, LinearRegression
data = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
target = [0, 1, 2]

ridge_model = Ridge(alpha=1e-8).fit(data, target)
print("RIDGE COEFS: " + str(ridge_model.coef_))
ols = LinearRegression().fit(data,target)
print("OLS COEFS: " + str(ols.coef_))

# RIDGE COEFS: [ 0.49999999  0.50000001]
# OLS COEFS: [ 0.5  0.5]
#
# VS. with alpha=0:
# RIDGE COEFS: [  1.57009246e-16   1.00000000e+00]
# OLS COEFS: [ 0.5  0.5]
```

**UPDATE**
The issue with an `alpha=0` as `int` above seems to only be an issue with a few toy problems like the example above.

For the housing data, the issue is one of scaling.  The 15-degree polynomial you invoke is causing numerical overflow.  To produce identical results from `LinearRegression` and `Ridge`, try scaling your data first:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, scale

dataset = pd.read_csv('house_price_data.csv')

# scale the X data to prevent numerical errors.
X = scale(dataset['sqft_living'].reshape(-1, 1))
Y = dataset['price'].reshape(-1, 1)

polyX = PolynomialFeatures(degree=15).fit_transform(X)

model1 = LinearRegression().fit(polyX, Y)
model2 = Ridge(alpha=0).fit(polyX, Y)

print("OLS Coefs: " + str(model1.coef_[0]))
print("Ridge Coefs: " + str(model2.coef_[0]))

#OLS Coefs: [  0.00000000e+00   2.69625315e+04   3.20058010e+04  -8.23455994e+04
#  -7.67529485e+04   1.27831360e+05   9.61619464e+04  -8.47728622e+04
#  -5.67810971e+04   2.94638384e+04   1.60272961e+04  -5.71555266e+03
#  -2.10880344e+03   5.92090729e+02   1.03986456e+02  -2.55313741e+01]
#Ridge Coefs: [  0.00000000e+00   2.69625315e+04   3.20058010e+04  -8.23455994e+04
#  -7.67529485e+04   1.27831360e+05   9.61619464e+04  -8.47728622e+04
#  -5.67810971e+04   2.94638384e+04   1.60272961e+04  -5.71555266e+03
#  -2.10880344e+03   5.92090729e+02   1.03986456e+02  -2.55313741e+01]
```

Comment: Thanks, but setting alpha to a very small positive float did not fix it. Please see the appended code and the plot it generates.

Comment: Scaling fixed it, thanks! Interesting how it overflows with ridge and not regular least squares. It probably happens when taking the norm of the coefficients, which are huge when calculated based on the unprocessed data.